# LogonUser with JNA leads to "unknown user name or bad password"

Tags: java, windows, winapi, jna

I try to implement a functionality to execute some application with certain credentials. For that I check if a logon with the credentials is possible.

```
import com.sun.jna.LastErrorException;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinBase;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class TestHarness {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {

        WinNT.HANDLEByReference phUser = new WinNT.HANDLEByReference();
        System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
        if (!Advapi32.INSTANCE.LogonUser("de313e", ".",
                "password", WinBase.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, WinBase.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, phUser)) {
            throw new LastErrorException(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError());
        }
    }
}
```

This unfortunately gives me

```
com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: GetLastError() returned 1326
```

The provided username is my current username. Why does this not work?

I am running it on Windows 10. My password contains some special characters like `!` and `&`. The user is named in:

[image]

Comment: Why are you using "." for your domain?   You should be using the machine or domain name.  (NB3DE2730054 or the result of `GetComputerNameEx`).

Comment: @DanielWiddis The documentation for `LogonUser ` has this to say: _'If this parameter is ".", the function validates the account by using only the local account database.'_ Perhaps that's indeed the desired behavior?

Comment: Ah, so it is. I tried the provided code and with valid username, ".", and password the error changed from 1326 to 1330.

Comment: Thanks for your support. You are right. If I change to "MASTDOM" it works. Or I needed to use `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS`. With the above code I created a lokal only user (which is not in domain), and it then works as well with the "."

Comment: Glad it works... I'll repost as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [LogonUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera) states for the parameter `lpszDomain`:

> A pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies the name of the
>   domain or server whose account database contains the lpszUsername
>   account. If this parameter is NULL, the user name must be specified in
>   UPN format. If this parameter is ".", the function validates the
>   account by using only the local account database.

Since you are using `"."` you are only validating against the local user database.  This would work for the `sysadmin` account on the local computer (NB3DE2730054).  However, you are attempting to validate a domain user, `de313e` so you must specify the domain, `MASTDOM`.

As an alternative you could set the domain to `null` and include the domain with the user: `de313e@MASTDOM`.  Or, as you've noted in the comments, if you use the logonType `LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS` and logonProvider `LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50` the `"."` will work.

Comment: can you please check, anything wrong entry in this code snippet https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63986530/logon-user-winapi32-java