# Logon User WinApi32 Java

Tags: java, authentication, winapi, jna

In the following code, need to check only login for the local user, not with domain, even with ".", code return with "GetLastError() returned 1326." with JNA jar 4.5.1. When jar 5.6.0 is used:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SIZE
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$HANDLEByReference.<init>(WinNT.java:871)
at com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT$HANDLEByReference.<init>(WinNT.java:867)
```

OS: Windows 10.

```java
HANDLEByReference phUser = new HANDLEByReference();
if(!Advapi32.INSTANCE.LogonUser(
        System.getProperty("user.name"),
        ".",
        "password",
        WinBase.LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK,
        WinBase.LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,phUser)) {
    System.out.println(new LastErrorException(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError()).getMessage();
}
```

Comment: The line number 871 in WinNT.java clearly indicates you're using an old version of `jna-platform` JAR.  You probably upgraded `jna` to 5.6.0 but are still using 4.5.1 for `jna-platform` (may be `platform` in that version).

Comment: You could check if the user you are using is in the local users list, with [`Get-LocalUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localuser?view=powershell-5.1) or `net user`. In addition to the jna version problem mentioned above, this api works in win32 sample.